# How to access the path before redirect (by replace())?

Tags: react-router

When visitors come to my website, if they're not logged in, they'll be redirected to a login page. This is done by the onEnter() (see code below). When redirect happens, I'd like to access and store the original path. But somehow I keep getting the post-redirect path, i.e. `/login`, from the redux store. How can I get the original one?

Here is the simplified code in my routes.js (I also use redux, hence the `store`).

```
...
export default (store) => {
  const requireLogin = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
    function checkAuth() {
      const { auth: {loggedIn} } = store.getState();
      if (!loggedIn) {
        replace('/login');
      }
      cb();
    }

    console.log(store.getState().routing.location.path); // here I always get the post-redirect path as opposed to the pre-redirect path
    if (!isAuthLoaded(store.getState())) {
      store.dispatch(loadAuth()).then(checkAuth);
    } else {
      checkAuth();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
        <Route path="postLoginPage" component={postLoginPage} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
  );
};
```

Comment: A common pattern is to encode the redirect URL into the login URL. e.g. `replace(\`/login?next=${encodeURIComponent(location.pathname)}\`)`, or something to that effect.